# Synchronization in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I read cuda reference manual for about synchronization in cuda but i don't know it clearly. for example why we use `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or `__syncthreads()`? if don't use them what happens, program can't work correctly? what difference between `cudaMemcpy` and `cudaMemcpyAsync` in action? 
can you show an example that show this difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is used in host code (i.e. running on the CPU) when it is desired that CPU activity wait on the completion of any pending GPU activity.  In many cases it's not necessary to do this explicitly, as GPU operations issued to a single stream are automatically serialized, and certain other operations like `cudaMemcpy()` have an inherent blocking device synchronization built into them.  But for some other purposes, such as debugging code, it may be convenient to force the device to finish any outstanding activity.

`__syncthreads()` is used in device code (i.e. running on the GPU) and may not be necessary at all in code that has independent parallel operations (such as adding two vectors together, element-by-element).  However, one example where it is commonly used is in algorithms that will operate out of shared memory.  In these cases it's frequently necessary to load values from global memory into shared memory, and we want each thread in the threadblock to have an opportunity to load it's appropriate shared memory location(s), before any actual processing occurs.  In this case we want to use `__syncthreads()` before the processing occurs, to ensure that shared memory is fully populated.  This is just one example.  `__syncthreads()` might be used any time synchronization within a block of threads is desired.  It does not allow for synchronization between blocks.

The difference between `cudaMemcpy` and `cudaMemcpyAsync` is that the non-async version of the call can only be issued to stream 0 and will block the calling CPU thread until the copy is complete.  The async version can optionally take a stream parameter, and returns control to the calling thread immediately, before the copy is complete.  The async version typically finds usage in situations where we want to have [asynchronous concurrent execution](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).

If you have basic questions about CUDA programming, it's recommended that you take some of the [webinars available](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars).

Comment: Is it possible to await just for a single device? Confusingly `cuCtxSynchronize` doc says "Blocks until _the device_ has completed all preceding requested tasks." But *which* device -- why can't they write "all devices" if that's what they mean. And then, how to block  on just one specific device.

Comment: This question mostly has the CUDA runtime API in view.  In the CUDA runtime API, `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` waits for just a single device.  `cuCtxSynchronize()` is from the driver API.  If you are writing a driver API application, then  `cuCtxSynchronize()` waits on the activity from that context.  A context has an inherent device association, but AFAIK it only waits for activity to complete *in that context*.

Comment: Thank you! I'm confused because the driver API does have e.g. `cuCtxCreate()`, and `cuCtxSynchronize()` does not take an argument of the `CUcontext` type. But yes, except for the broad title mine is a separate question...

Comment: The driver API has a notion of the "current" context as well as a context stack.  Many operations in the driver API operate on the current context (just as many operations in the runtime API operate on the current device, like `cudaMalloc()`.  I won't be able to give a tutorial on the driver API in the space of comments.

Comment: The documentation made it clear here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX.html

Answer (score 2):

Moreover, `__syncthreads()` becomes really necessary when you have some conditional paths in your code, and then you want to run an operation that depends on several array element.
Consider the following example:

```
int n = threadIdx.x;

if( myarray[n] > 0 )
{
     myarray[n] = - myarray[n];
}
double y = myarray[n] + myarray[n+1]; // Not all threads reaches here at the same time
```

In the above example, not all threads will have the same execution sequence. Some threads will take longer based on the `if` condition. When considering the last line of the example, you need to make sure that all the threads had exactly finished the if-condition and updated `myarray` correctly. If this wasn't the case, `y` may use some updated and non-updated values.
In this case, it becomes a must to add `__syncthreads()` before evaluating `y` to overcome this problem:

```
if( myarray[n] > 0 )
{
     myarray[n] = - myarray[n];
}
__syncthreads(); // All threads will wait till they come to this point
// We are now quite confident that all array values are updated.
double y = myarray[n] + myarray[n+1];
```

Comment: What happens if a thread returns from the function call and never calls __syncthreads()?